# Laravel 5.3 login throttling

Tags: laravel-5, throttling

How do I enable login throttling in Laravel 5.3?
Should it be enabled by default?
Where can it be configured?
I could not find anything in the config files. I use ldap auth with adldap library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple.
In .env, If CACHE_DRIVER is set to array, it won't work.
Set CACHE_DRIVER to file for example.

Comment: It is .env CACHE_DRIVER=file
Mine was array. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According [to the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#login-throttling):

> If you are using Laravel's built-in LoginController class, the  Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins trait will already be included in your controller. By default, the user will not be able to login for one minute if they fail to provide the correct credentials after several attempts

Comment: It would be great. But it seems there is no limitation. I can try to log in several times. No locking. Where is the config so I can see how many tries are possible?

Comment: What did you tried exactly: connect 10 times with wrong login, then connect one with correct login?

Comment: Something like that. To be honest i would like to lock myself out. That is the plan. So it seems this throttling does not work for me.